# Homomorphisms from infinite groups to finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

We know that the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is equal to $(n,m)$, the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $m$. Also, the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is going to $m$.

My question is, how many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

We have $$\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z} = \langle (1,0), (0,1): n \cdot (1,0) = 0\rangle,$$ so determining a homomorphism can be done by specifying the image of the generators. Hence we need to send $(1,0)$ to an element that satisfies $n \cdot \phi(1,0) = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Again there are $(n,m)$ ways to do this, moreover we need to send $(0,1)$ to something, and as mentioned sending this to any element of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ will define a homomorphism.

Can we then say the number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is $(n,m)\cdot m$?

Comment: Yes, we can!${}$

Comment: @markvs: Thank you for the quick reply! More generally if we know the number of homomorphisms from $G$ to $K$ is $a$ and the number of homomorphisms from $H$ to $K$ is $b$, then the number of homomorphisms from $G \times H$ to $K$ is $ab$? Or is there something special about the situation above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $K$ is an Abelian group and there are $a$ homomorphisms $G\to K$ and $b$ homomorphisms $H\to K$ then the number $c$ of homomorphism $G\times H\to K$ is $ab$. Indeed, if $\phi_1:G\to K$, $\phi_2:H\to K$ are homomorphisms then $\phi: (g,h)\mapsto \phi_1(g)\phi_2(h)$ is a homomorphism $G\times H\to K$ since $K$ is Abelian. Its restrictions to $G\times 1$ and $1\times H$ are $\phi_1,\phi_2$. Hence $c\ge ab$.

On the other hand for every homomorphism $\phi$ from $G\times H\to K$, its restrictions to $G\times 1$ and $1\times H$ are homomorphisms $\phi_1,\phi_2$ such that $\phi(g,h)=\phi_1(g,1)\phi_2(1,h)$. So $c\le ab$.

Thus $c=ab$.